# WebapplicationIntializer issue on new tomcat version 70100

Tags: java, tomcat

We have a webapp that uses WebapplicationInitializer and does  not have web.xml. This webapp worked fine on tomcat 7.0.99 but fails to work on tomcat 7.0.100. Version. This is an spring mvc app used annotations and WebApplicationInitializer to configure. Please let me know if there is any setting that needs to added to tomcat conf . Hoping for not updating the webapp code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem

This is a bug

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64191

Will be fixed in version 7.0.103 https://github.com/apache/tomcat/releases/tag/7.0.103

Comment: Is there any released version of tomcat 7 above tomcat 7.0.100 that solve the issue ? Please mention it in your answer

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by adding 1. web.xml and define default servlet 2. adding servlet xml file where I added scan code base tag and also bean definition tags for ApplicationInitializer class. Then I could see the code started to work. I hope tomcat 7.0.100 has a flag that could set to true or false to retain previous functionality.

Comment: can you share web.xml and servlet.xml in some way?